# Taking nearly 400 MB of memory at android app startup

Tags: java, android, android-profiler

First of all, I have seen other questions which might be a duplicate of mine. But none of them could provide me with solution.
[image: This is what profiler gave me about memory usage]

There is too much memory consumption at the app startup compared to when it is reached in MainActivity. 
At Application class , there is only analytic and facebook sdk initialization. Splash activity contains only logic to check whether user has login before or not. Any Idea what is behind this ? Thanks for paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Studio's memory profiler to see what objects are being allocated and what causes these allocations. It can show you stacktrase of every object allocation. See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler) please.

Comment: I have seen the docs, the stacktrace can only be done at the beginning of the dotted line. The Mountain at the start of the graph can't be traced. That's why I am asking the question @Dizarry. Thanks for your effort